# So many time to push an react native to git

Tags: react-native, github, gitlab

Im get so many time to push an react-native project to git someone know why this happen
it's take more time on writing objects

Answer (score 1):

There are many files that do not need to be checked into Github.
Your biggest directory is probably node_modules. This directory does not need to be check in to Github because these are your project dependencies which are downloaded with the command nom install when you check out the project.
Then you have your build directory which are your compiled/generated files that are always rebuilt when you build.

To avoid checking in these files to Github, create a .gitignore file. On separate lines, add the files/directory that you do not need (ex: node_modules/). Here is a React Native starter project .gitignore file. You should be good with this one: https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit/blob/master/.gitignore